# react-rails error: invariant violation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails), and everything works fine until I press the back button of the browser and go to the previous page. I get the error below.

> Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.

I get the same error when I press the back button of the browser, or go back a page with a keyboard press. Please help me out!

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party React packages? The version of React included in react-rails doesn't tend to cooperate well with third party React packages. I've ended up removing //= require react from my application.js and I manually load in the npm version instead.

Comment: I have `//= require react`, `//= require react_ujs`, `//= require react-bootstrap`. I did read somewhere that `react-bootstrap` has its own version of react included.

Comment: How do you manually load the npm version? Don't I eventually have to include react in `application.js`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Error (Only a ReactOwner can have refs.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663175/react-error-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs)